# Binding a wx.html2.WebView.New Widget?

Tags: python, wxpython, wxwidgets

I would like to bind the wx.html2.WebView.New widget with wx.EVT_LEFT_UP  however it doesnt work (it doesnt get noticed, nothing happens).

Is there anything i am missing?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you are missing anything, this hasn't yet been implemented. Mouse and keyboard events are high on my todo list though, I will update this question when they have been added.